# Alignment shift between Firefox / other browsers

Tags: html, css, firefox, alignment

http://jsfiddle.net/Fy5v8/

I haven't been able to solve this issue, or seen it before—it's subtle, but I of course want it to be perfect. I don't see any reason why it should be displaying strangely.

The bottom of the image and the navigation should be aligned, but are not. Here is the incorrect version in firefox:

http://jamimiles.com/firefox.png

Or visit it on your own browsers. Thanks so much for your help!

```
#header {
font-family: georgia, serif;
width:800px;
height:65px;
font-size:20px; font-size:2rem;
color:#3a3b59;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-align:left;
padding:0 0 30px 0;
margin-top:0;
border-bottom: none;
float:left;
position:relative;
}
#header ul li {
list-style-type:none;
line-height:20px; line-height:2rem;
float:right;
}

#header li {
padding-left:20px;
}

#header ul {
margin-top:52px;
padding:0;
float:right;
margin-bottom:0;
}

#header img {
padding:0; 
border:none;
float:left;
}
```

That's the CSS. Here is the header band.

```
    <div id="header">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/namebanner3.png"></a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="portfolio.html">portfolio</a></li>
                            <li><a href="JamiMiles_Resume.pdf" target="blank">resum&eacute;</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a JSFiddle

Comment: jsfiddle has been added

Comment: Recommend to use CSS Reset .

Comment: remove margin-top:52px; in #header ul (optional) then position the header absolutely and add bottom:0;. Advice: when faced with alighnment issues, use background colors and borders to help identify whats wrong

Comment: thanks for the advice, olumide! position:absolute worked, with some tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

Try tweaking the img px. You are currently set at 851px by 141px

```
<img  height="#" width="#" style="-webkit-user-select: none"     

 src="http://jamimiles.com/firefox.png">
```